# Trigger updatedAt=NOW() for hunded-thousand rows will not actual

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I am using SQL Trigger to update `updatedAt` column if there is a new data inserted/updated in PG 9.6.

Here is the function that will be called by trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_updatedatstamp() RETURNS trigger AS $updatedat_stamp$
  BEGIN
    NEW."updatedAt" := now();
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$updatedat_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the trigger script

```
create trigger tg_de_installment_cdcupdatedat before
insert or update
    on
    public.table for each row execute procedure sp_updatedatstamp()
```

Here is the Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "type" text NULL,
    "transactionDate" timestamptz NULL,
    remark text NULL,
    "createdAt" timestamptz NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamptz NULL,
    "deletedAt" timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This code is working fine with small data, **until** an application execute bulk update query (100K+ rows will be updated) that takes 30 minutes.

The trigger will makes all 100k+ rows uses `updatedAt` of first rows, which makes the other rows `updatedAt` not correct. At the end, our data pipeline with schedule 5 min, will lose this data. Is there a way to makes the SQL Trigger uses it actual timestamp for huge data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As stated in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, **their values do not change during the transaction**. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the “current” time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So if you want a different value for each call, use `clock_timestamp()`